# Scala, Quill - how to use SQL IN clause in quill query?

Tags: postgresql, scala, quill, scala-cats

I have a database, which model looks like:

```
case class Data {
  id: Int, 
  value: Json
}
```

I would like to create search query which can filter some fields from `value` JSON by `csv`:

```
def search(id: Int) = {
  ....
  val list = List("value1", "value2", "value3")
  quote(
    myTable.filter( t => t.id == lift(id)))
    .dynamic
    .filter(_ => liftQuery(list).contains(infix""" t.name """.pure.as[Boolean]))
}
```

The problem is it does not work well. I would have no idea how I could use `IN` clause here in other way.
`value` is a JSON which include field `name` and now I would like to search all elements in `myTable` which fit to values pass in `list`.
I tried also do something like:

```
infix""" t.name in ${list.mkString(",")} """.pure.as[Boolean]
```

But it also did not work. Can you help me with some solution? There is no good example of `IN` clause in quill docs.

Comment: So values in the `value` column are JSON objects that have a field `name`, like this: `{"name": "value1"}`? And you'd like to find all rows where the value of `name` is included in the list, like in this query: `select * from data where value->>'name' in ('value1', 'value2');` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```scala
quote(query[Data].filter(d => liftQuery(list).contains(infix"value->>'name'")))
```

results in:

```
SELECT d.id, d.value FROM data d WHERE value->>'name' IN (?, ?, ?)
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/t4YItAweTna6P5dEw1JRTg

Comment: Hm, looks like same as I tried. What is the difference between your code and my in above example: `filter(_ => liftQuery(list).contains(infix""" t.name """.pure.as[Boolean]))`?

Comment: I used `->>` to access a string value of a JSON object field. See https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/ for more details. Also, I dropped `.pure.as[Boolean]` because it wasn't needed.